# Disabling data url jpg cache

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser, jpeg

I have a constant source of base64 encoded jpg files roughly 1-5 images per second creating a simple video stream. This is how they look like:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

Entering them into src atribute of img element triggers requests in the background which are being cached by the browser:

[image: Screenshot from Chrome network tab]

Since every frame is cached my app fills the browser cache after a short time.

1. How can I avoid this caching behaviour so that every frame is either not cached or cached for a really short amount of time?
2. If that is not possible then how can I display jpg binary data coming from a stream reasonably fast* and without caching?

* I tried using [jpg.js](https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs) in order to decode raw binary jpg data into raw pixels and render them on a Canvas but that is too costly in terms of time and CPU consumption

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that - it's tricky, but possible. It involves [converting dataURI to Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12300351/4471582) and then blob to [objectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). I've prepared an example with one picture, but you can do a lot. Every time a different URL will be created, so no caching.

My example: https://jsbin.com/tuxoveroha/edit?html,output

Just make sure you use [revokeObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) when done with the URL, to free up memory.

Comment: Thanks. JSbin example is amazing.

Comment: I know this is old, but it just helped me out tremendously - thanks!