# How to force OpenLayers to deallocate memory for locally stored vector tiles no longer in use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, openlayers

I am currently working on an Ionic/Capacitor/React app for Android where the end user needs to display a map while offline.

In order to achieve this, I'm trying to display locally stored vector tiles (in `pbf`format) in Open Layers.

I'm able to display the layer just fine, however it seems there is a memory leak somewhere. As I'm trying to move around the map, memory used by the app (as seen in Android Studio Profiler) keeps increasing until it reaches 1.1-1.2GB and the app crashes.

Here is how the `Map` object is initialized :

```ts
export async function initMap(
  mapElement: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
  uri: string,
  availableTilesPath: Set<string> | null
) {
  const mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
    coordinateFormat: createStringXY(4),
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
  });

  const sourceGWCTMSLocalTiles = new VectorTileSource({
    format: new MVT(),
    url: `${uri}/${vectorArchiveFileName}/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf`,
    tileGrid: olTilegrid.createXYZ({ maxZoom: 14, tileSize: 2048 }),
    tileLoadFunction: (tile, url) =>
      customTileLoad(tile as VectorTile, url, availableTilesPath),
  });
  const vectorLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
    renderMode: "vector",
    source: sourceGWCTMSLocalTiles,
  });

  return new Map({
    target: mapElement.current || undefined,
    layers: [
      vectorLayer,
      new WebGLTileLayer({
        source: sourceGeoTIFF,
      }),
    ],
    view: new View({
      projection: "EPSG:3857",
      zoom: 16,
      minZoom: 6,
      maxZoom: 20,
      center: fromLonLat([-52.159, 4.005]),
      constrainResolution: true,
      showFullExtent: true,
    }),
    controls: defaultControls().extend([mousePositionControl]),
  });
}
```

Here is the custom tile load function which is called in order to load data from the app's storage:

```ts
export function customTileLoad(
  tile: VectorTile,
  url: string,
  availableTilesPaths: Set<string> | null
) {
  tile.setLoader(function (extent, resolution, projection) {
    const sliceAt = url.indexOf(vectorArchiveFileName);
    const fileUri = url.substring(sliceAt + vectorArchiveFileName.length);
     
    //prevent unecessary calls to the filesystem
    if (availableTilesPaths?.has(vectorArchiveFileName + fileUri)) {
      Filesystem.readFile({
        directory: Directory.External,
        path: vectorArchiveFileName + fileUri,
      })
        .then((res) => {
          const str = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + res.data;
          fetch(str)
            .then((res) => res.arrayBuffer())
            .then(function (data) {
              const format = tile.getFormat(); // ol/format/MVT configured as source format

              //no more memory leak if I comment out the following lines
              const features = format.readFeatures(data, {
                extent: extent,
                featureProjection: projection,
              });
              tile.setFeatures(features as Feature<Geometry>[]);
            });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log("error trying to load tile");
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Lib versions :
OpenLayers : 7.4.0,
Ionic : 7.0.12
Capacitor : 5.0.4
React : 18.2.0

At first I thought I was misusing the Capacitor Filesystem plugin and forgetting to call close on a resource or something of the sort.
However, commenting out everything inside the `readFile` callback resulted in no memory increase.

Then I thought it might have to do with a memory leak in the `fetch` API, as suggested by [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69932559/how-do-i-fix-or-work-around-this-memory-leak-in-fetch). I manually converted my base64 string to an array buffer using a for loop, without using fetch and it did not change anything.

Then I thought it might be linked to Ionic's inner browser caching all the tiles, as suggested by [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492858/chrome-memory-leak-when-displaying-base64-images). However I was not able to implement the answer as I'm using an ArrayBuffer and OL's  `MVT`format's `readFeatures` method won't allow anything other than an array buffer.

Comment: You should find what objects are not released, try connecting Chrome Devtools and using the memory profiler. There is probably a data structure somewhere that holds references to your tiles.